# Sql server 2005 how to create a database from a dump of a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 files log.ldf and data.mdf thats suppose to be  dump from a database .
how can i create a new database with this old dump ?

Comment: Are you taking about Microsft DB? In that case use Microsoft Sever MAnagement Studio Restore

Comment: These are not dumps. These are actual database files. You will need to _attach_ them, _not restore_ them.

Comment: attach them can you tell me how ?

Comment: @geomagas LMGTFY is not allowed in SO, please do not use it.

Comment: Comment withdrawn, sorry if I offended anyone. Having said that, some people think LMGTFY is rude, but some _don't_. I think fairness should account more than "niceness". LMGTFYing lazy people seems fair to me. And a little sarcasm never hurt anyone, in fact it _could_ prevent others from being lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS open the object explorer and connect to your server.
Expand the server by clicking on the plus [+] sign next to the server.
Right-click on the 'Databases' folder and choose 'Attach...'
Click the 'Add' button and navigate to the files to attach the database files to your server.

Comment: i did what you said but it gave me this error 

The database 'MOP' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 611 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

Comment: You are trying to attach a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to a SQL Server 2005 server. You'll need to use 2008 R2 or 2012 to open the database files. There is no way around this.